# How to drop negative values from data frame and save them in a separate data frame?

Tags: python-3.x, data-analysis

I want to remove the negative value which are available in column pop95 and pdenpavg and save these negative values to a separate dataset and drop them from the original dataset.

I have tried the following code but it shows an empty data set while the original data set clearly shows some negative values in it.

```
df3 = df2[(df2['pop95']<0) & (df2['pdenpavg']<0)]
df3
```

Answer (score 0):

There won't be any change to `df2`, but the code to generate `df3` looks fine.

Are you want do an "and" instead of an "or" here. I suspect that it is probably because there was no such row where both 'pop95' and 'pdenpavg' values were negative at the same time.

Comment: or operator gives me same empty data frame while there are so many negative value in both columns like -6.091846e+07

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
df3 = df2[(df2['pop95']<0) & (df2['pdenpavg']<0)]
df2 = df2.drop(df3.copy().index)
```

Comment: Seems like it is working. df2 doesn't have negative values anymore. But when I print df3 it shows empty data frame. It should be printing out all the values which are less than zero, right?

Comment: @AsraKhalid Strange it should stay there, can you try again?

Comment: I did. It just shows the column names without any rows.

Comment: @AsraKhalid I edited it, does it work now, copy it again